# Python splinter fill out text inside iframe

Tags: python, selenium, crm, splinter

I'm automating the autoraptor CRM with splinter and everything was running smooth until it came time to compose a message. The CRM's email editor is inside an iframe. I can find the iframe with splinter but i can't get it to write anything in the editor.

---

**Here is the html**

```
<div id="cke_1_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: 200px;"><span id="cke_67" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span><iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" title="Rich Text Editor, email_body" aria-describedby="cke_67" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe></div>
```

I have read [Frames, alerts and prompts](http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iframes-and-alerts.html)

**Here is the Python**

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

from splinter import Browser
import urlparse
import time

# Creds
username = "lumberjack@imok.com"
password = "spamspamspam..."

login_url = 'https://ar.autoraptor.com/login'

browser = Browser('chrome')

#help(browser)

# Go to login page
browser.visit(login_url)

# Fill in Username
browser.find_by_name('login').fill(username)

# Fill in 
browser.find_by_name('password').fill(password)

# Click the login Button
browser.find_by_value('Log In').click()

# Navigate to upsheets
#browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav"]/li[4]/a').click()

# Navigate to least updated upsheets
url = "https://ar.autoraptor.com/upsheets?filter=active&sort=updated_at%5B1%5D"
browser.visit(url)

# Click on notifications
browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav"]/li[8]/div[1]').click()
time.sleep(5)

# Click on email
browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="notification-tab-incoming_email"]/div').click()
time.sleep(5)

# Read email
browser.find_by_text("Email from ").click()

# Send email
browser.find_by_id('newemailplaceholder').click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_by_id("cke_1_contents").fill("ftw")
#browser.quit()
```

**Here's the traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testbot.py", line 50, in <module>
    browser.find_by_id("cke_1_contents").find_by_tag("iframe").fill("foo")
  File "/home/ricky/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py", line 529, in fill
    self.value = value
  File "/home/ricky/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py", line 511, in _set_value
    self._element.clear()
  File "/home/ricky/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 92, in clear
    self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/ricky/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/ricky/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ricky/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.10.0-26-generic x86_64)
```

Comment: Please post your code. What happens when you try it?

Comment: Instead of clearing the element within the iframe, can you select it first? Get it's content? If not, the switch to iframe is not successful and that's what you need to focus on.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the exception is that IFrames cannot be typed in even when the HTML5 attribute `contenteditable="true"`. If you have any control over the HTML, try this below and you'll see that you can actually edit a paragraph if it has the attribute above. What you might be able to do if the HTML is out of your control is find an element *within* the Iframe (if there is one) that allows you to interact with it. If there are no elements within the Iframe, then you'll have to resort to a mouse/keyboard controller means of interacting with the Iframe, which means physically moving the mouse and simulating keystrokes.

```
<div id="cke_1_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: 200px;">
    <span id="cke_67" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span>
    <iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" title="Rich Text Editor, email_body" aria-describedby="cke_67" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
        <p contenteditable="true">Begin with some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have any control over the html the crm is owned by a third party https://www.autoraptor.com/

Comment: Maybe i could write a proxy the could tamper with the html.

Comment: Writing the proxy now